# Stumbling across getline, fstream, scope inconsistency

Tags: c++, fstream, getline

I'm reading up on std::getline(), but I'm not figuring out what I'm doing wrong. In this scenario, I'm unsure why my user_input variable, which is declared in the main function block and defined as "0", will correctly be modified to "2" in an inner block that modifies it, but then be set to "NULL" afterwards in the main function block.

My understanding is that when things are modified in a nested block, the outer block does not recognize the changes--they never leaves the inner block's scope.

My best guess is that it must have something to do with my file-opening and file-closing things, or that I don't know how getline interacts with them. I've done lots of cin and cout over the past year, but haven't touched getline, nor file interaction either.

```
//fake_main.cpp

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    //---|Initializations|---
    std::string user_input = "0";
    //user_input is 0 in this block

    std::ofstream outbound_filestream;
    outbound_filestream.open ("a.txt");
    outbound_filestream << "2" << std::endl;
    outbound_filestream.close();

    std::ifstream inbound_filestream;

    //verifying that there is a "2" in my otherwise empty file
    inbound_filestream.open ("a.txt");
    if (inbound_filestream.is_open())
    {
        while (std::getline(inbound_filestream, user_input))
        {
            std::cout << user_input << '\n';
            //user_input is 2
        }
        inbound_filestream.close();
    //right here, after losing scope, user_input is NULL, not 0.
    }
    //and then, following suit, user_input is NULL here, not 0 or 2.

    //---|Main Program|---

    intro(user_input);

    //snip

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think about what the last call of `std::getline()` has read, and why it returned `false`, thus the loop ended.

Comment: Oh jeeze. Oh jeeze, oh jeeze. You're telling me that it's putting in an empty line because it gets called twice, not once? I feel so foolish. I'll confirm I can get it working before marking it solved.

Comment: I don't think you really mean `NULL`, do you?

Comment: _"My understanding is that when things are modified in a nested block, the outer block does not recognize the changes--they never leaves the inner block's scope._" No, that's not quite right. The lifetime of objects follows this rule, but any modifications you make to extant objects during a scope will persist after exiting from the scope; it doesn't all get "rolled back" or anything.

Comment: I had thought it was NULL, because it was simply a blank space, and because I had previously observed before similar behavior to my program errors that had been caused by a variable accidentally set to NULL. It was an erroneous assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines

```
    while (std::getline(inbound_filestream, user_input)) {
    }
```

will read input into the `user_input` variable until no more input is available. Thus the content you want to have is only available inside of the loop body.

The last cycle that exits the loop, will set `user_input` empty.

If you want to collect all the input from the stream line by line, you may have an extra variable to just read the line:

```
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(inbound_filestream,line)) {
        user_input += line;
    }
```

Comment: It turns out that while you're right about this being a problem, I was entirely wrong in thinking that I had found this to be the root of the problem. I thought I had isolated the cause of my larger issue, which is that right now, my program is running through everything without stopping to get input from the user, even though I have std::getline(std::cin, variable_name) everywhere. So thanks for your help, and I'm going to mark it as correct, but I guess I should be making a new question after doing a bit more sifting.

Comment: I finally fixed the issue, if you're interested in knowing, or in explaining this tangential discrepancy to me. I have an input-parsing function of type string. In it, I use "getline(cin, input)", but before it, I had (during manual debugging) put "cin >> input", and input is of type string. Because I tried to cin to a string, it "locked" my input stream and I couldn't enter anything else. Is there anything you or anyone else reading can tell me about this behavior so I understand what's going on behind the scenes?